# Get original value of Tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, instance-variables

I'm learning tensorflow right now and I have made a habit in programming of printing my variables to see what I'm working with as I'm coding. I can't figure out how to print the values of `constant` and `Variable` objects in `tensorflow`

**How can I get back the values that I assigned to the instances?**

```
import tensorflow as tf

C_int = tf.constant(134)
#Tensor("Const_11:0", shape=TensorShape([]), dtype=int32)
V_mat = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,3]))
#<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x10672fa10>
C_str = tf.constant("ABC")
#Tensor("Const_16:0", shape=TensorShape([]), dtype=string)


C_int
#134
V_mat
#array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
C_str
#ABC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to see the values of your tensors is to create a [`tf.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session) and use [`Session.run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) to evaluate the tensors. Thus, your code would look like:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

C_int = tf.constant(134)
V_mat = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,3]))
C_str = tf.constant("ABC")

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(C_int)
#134
sess.run(V_mat)
#array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
sess.run(C_str)
#ABC

sess.close()
```

Comment: that makes sense since you have to run the graph to see the objects, right?